# Converting the date and time column into an SQL format date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update/convert a string of date and time, into a SQL Date and time format, i.e it would look exactly the same, but it would not read as a nvarchar, but as date and time.

```
Date            Time
20-10-2019  12:00:00
20-10-2019  11:00:00
20-10-2019  10:00:00
20-10-2019  09:00:00
20-10-2019  08:00:00
20-10-2019  07:00:00
```

I gathered this data from a site using pandas, the converted it into a dataframe and then inserted it into the MSSQL server, where there was already a table created.

I did this so far

```
SELECT CONVERT (date,'19-10-2019') as Date
SELECT CONVERT (time,'17:00:00',120) as Time;
```

But this only converts one column, whereas I wanted to convert the entire column, and save it as another another column (I made that too).

```
alter table <table_name>
add <col_name> date

alter table <table_name>
add <col_name> time
```

Can anyone please help out, since I have scoured the web for some time, and could not get the appropriate results, and I mostly get this error:

'''Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'''

Comment: If I may hazard a guess, it is giving you the problem because it is expecting date in format `MM-dd-yyyy`, but `20` in your date is not a valid month. Try working around that.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date by style 105. [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CONVERT(DATE, '20-10-2019', 105), CONVERT(TIME, '12:00:00')
```

And for update all rows

```
UPDATE table SET NewDateColumn = CONVERT(DATE, [Date], 105), 
                 NewTimeColumn = CONVERT(TIME, [Time])
```

Comment: The last statement is giving me this output: 

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: But that problem is only coming for time, not for the date. The date conversion worked fine.

Comment: it looks like you have empty or invalid time text.

Comment: the time text is like this 12:00:00, and the 'Time' column is not empty. However, the new column (Converted_time) is set to null (since I used ALTER table).

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string date or time into a date and time format,

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, '20-10-2019', 105) as [Date], TRY_CAST('12:00:00' AS TIME) as [Time]
```

For update

```
UPDATE table SET datecol = TRY_CONVERT(DATE, DateString, 105), 
                 timecol = TRY_CAST(TimeString AS time)
```

Comment: It does convert it, but not the entire column. Since, I have already tried this, and the data remains unchanged. It shows a row of changed data, and that's it. I checked using the SELECT * from [table_name].

Answer (score 0):

First, you have bad data in the columns.  You should find that.  You can use:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHRE TRY_CONVERT(date, t.datecol) IS NULL OR 
     TRY_CONVERT(time, t.timecol) IS NULL;
```

Note:  You might want to add a format for the `date` conversion, but if the default methods work (as they seem to in your case), that may not be necessary.

Once the data is fixed, or you decide you are happy with `NULL` values for the bad values, then you have two choices.

You can add computed columns:

```
alter table t add real_date as (try_convert(date, t.datecol));
alter table t add real_time as (try_convert(time, t.timecol));
```

Or, you can alter the columns in place:

```
-- first convert to default string formats
update t
    set datecol = try_convert(date, t.datecol),
        timecol  = try_convert(time, t.timecol);

-- then alter the types
alter t alter column datecol date;
alter t alter column timecol time;
```